# how to connect to Servo Drive(googoltech CDHD ServoDrive ethercat) using ros_Ethercat and ros_control

Tags: ros, xml, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not found any documents about how to connect to Servo Drive(googoltech CDHD servo drive) using Ethercat bus and ros_control in ROS website.

I use the joint trajectory controller (inside the  ros_controller_manager) as the low-level contorl and  use moveit package to carry out the high-level planning and  use qt to design the UI, now i need to   send low-level contorl conputing result to the servo Drive and get data from it through the Ethercat Bus.i have no idea about this,can anyone give me a hand ?

Thanks in advace!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199494/how-to-connect-to-servo-drive(googoltech-cdhd-servodrive-ethercat)-using-ros_ethercat--and-ros_control/) by [jackchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21114/jackchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what you are looking for is http://wiki.ros.org/soem

" SOEM is an open source EtherCAT master library written in c"

It supports SoE and CoE based drives according to the feature list (as well as many other EtherCAT features), however I've not personally tried it on anything.

---

Originally posted by [evanmj](https://answers.ros.org/users/47/evanmj/) with karma: 250 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jackchen,

I have been working on it for the past 4 months, If you are still struck at the same issue above mentioned, The following information can be useful,

" SOEM is an open source EtherCAT master library written in c" which is available @ https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM . After that try to go through the example codes in following link https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM/tree/master/test/linux

1. Download the repository SOEM-master and create a build  directory  in the path according to you ../../SOEM-master/
2. Then again crate a test directory in side your build directory ../../SOEM-master/build/test/
3. Now compile the package alone using cmake .. & make commands in the path ../../SOEM-master/
4. Then find the executables generated in the path ../../SOEM-master/build/test/
5. Connect your motor drive using Ethernet cable to your PC
6. Try to run the simple_test  executable with sudo permissions as follows sudo ./simpple_test eth0 or eth1
7. Try to understand the response got from the ethercat slave drive like name, id , revision and cross check with the    manufacturer data sheet
8. Now decide yourself in which mode you want to run the ethercat slaves for example cyclic synchronous torque mode  you can get the example code in the following link https://gist.github.com/manuelvonthron-opalrt/9467152
9. Below are the best web links to extend the application code for your requirement
   http://www.elmomc.com/support/manuals/MAN-CAN301IG.pdf
   https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNgcv7v5jQAhUOUI8KHce9AhAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.anaheimautomation.com%2Fmanuals%2Fservo%2FEtherCATUser%27sManual%2520(1).pdf&usg=AFQjCNEvfwHhdDqv1cXLFjkPOZX-YBQROw

---

Originally posted by [TraiBo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28181/traibo/) with karma: 146 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1